# Error while upgrading spring-boot version to 2.7.14. creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory defined in class path resource

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am getting following error in some of my Junits in my project while trying to upgrade spring boot version from 2.3.9.RELEASE to 2.7.14 (and updated spring-framework version to 5.3.29). I am kind of new to spring. Need some help to resolve this issue or tell me how I can approach to debug and resolve this issue. I am just going through internet and doing different combinations in my Pom file.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource \[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class\]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate \[org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean\]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1157) \~\[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:911) \~\[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) \~\[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) \[spring-boot-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) \[spring-boot-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) \[spring-boot-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14\]
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:136) \[spring-boot-test-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14\]
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:141) \[spring-test-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:90) \[spring-test-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124) \[spring-test-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118) \[spring-test-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) \[spring-test-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248) \[spring-test-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) \[spring-test-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) \[spring-test-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) \[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2\]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) \[spring-test-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) \[spring-test-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) \[spring-test-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331) \[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2\]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79) \[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2\]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329) \[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2\]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66) \[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2\]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293) \[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2\]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) \[spring-test-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) \[spring-test-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306) \[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2\]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413) \[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2\]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) \[spring-test-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365) \[surefire-junit4-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2\]
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273) \[surefire-junit4-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2\]
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238) \[surefire-junit4-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2\]
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159) \[surefire-junit4-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2\]
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384) \[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2\]
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345) \[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2\]
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126) \[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2\]
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418) \[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2\]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate \[org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean\]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties$Naming.lambda$applyNamingStrategies$1(HibernateProperties.java:178) \~\[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14\]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties$Naming.lambda$applyNamingStrategy$2(HibernateProperties.java:187) \~\[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14\]
at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1129) \~\[?:1.8.0_321\]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties$Naming.applyNamingStrategy(HibernateProperties.java:187) \~\[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14\]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties$Naming.applyNamingStrategies(HibernateProperties.java:177) \~\[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14\]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties$Naming.access$000(HibernateProperties.java:146) \~\[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14\]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.getAdditionalProperties(HibernateProperties.java:102) \~\[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14\]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineHibernateProperties(HibernateProperties.java:95) \~\[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14\]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.getVendorProperties(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:131) \~\[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14\]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:132) \~\[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14\]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) \~\[?:1.8.0_321\]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) \~\[?:1.8.0_321\]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) \~\[?:1.8.0_321\]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) \~\[?:1.8.0_321\]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387) \~\[?:1.8.0_321\]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) \~\[?:1.8.0_321\]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355) \~\[?:1.8.0_321\]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) \~\[?:1.8.0_321\]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties$Naming.lambda$applyNamingStrategies$1(HibernateProperties.java:178) \~\[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14\]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties$Naming.lambda$applyNamingStrategy$2(HibernateProperties.java:187) \~\[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14\]
at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1129) \~\[?:1.8.0_321\]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties$Naming.applyNamingStrategy(HibernateProperties.java:187) \~\[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14\]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties$Naming.applyNamingStrategies(HibernateProperties.java:177) \~\[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14\]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties$Naming.access$000(HibernateProperties.java:146) \~\[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14\]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.getAdditionalProperties(HibernateProperties.java:102) \~\[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14\]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineHibernateProperties(HibernateProperties.java:95) \~\[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14\]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.getVendorProperties(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:131) \~\[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14\]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:132) \~\[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14\]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) \~\[?:1.8.0_321\]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) \~\[?:1.8.0_321\]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) \~\[?:1.8.0_321\]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) \~\[?:1.8.0_321\]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29\]
```

I am just going through internet and doing different combinations in my Pom file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of your problem is :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
```

It seems that in the upgrade a class have been removed or is not present.
You could add this property : spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=default

But I advise you to upgrade your hibernate version too if you fixed it yourself.

This answer to a similar problem might provide a solution to your : https://stackoverflow.com/a/72126360/929227

Comment: Thanks for the help. My issue got resolved after upgrading the hibernate-core version to 5.6.15 from 5.2.12